# Is there a way to reduce the height of each element in a NavigationRail in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Let's say I have the following NavigationRail:

[image]

I'm aware that this widget is quite new, and as such, its functionality may be limited. However, I'd like to know if there's any way to reduce the height of each element in a NavigationRail, such as the element I indicated on the image above, as it seems that the parameters in the NavigationRail widget don't allow for such a thing as of now.

EDIT: I did what chunhunghan told, and even so, the problem still persists. Even using a container, the width and the height of each element remains the same. My code:

```dart
class _HomePageState extends ModularState<HomePage, HomeController> {

  int selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          NavigationRail(
            onDestinationSelected: (index) {
              selectedIndex = index;
            },
            backgroundColor: navigationRailColor,
            selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
            destinations: [
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon:
                Container(height: 200, child: Icon(Icons.favorite_border)),
                selectedIcon:
                Container(height: 200, child: Icon(Icons.favorite)),
                label: Text(''),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.book),
                label: Text(''),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.star_border),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.star),
                label: Text(''),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `Container` wrap `icon` and provide `height` 
I use a large value 200 for demo purpose

```
 NavigationRailDestination(
                icon:
                    Container(height: 200, child: Icon(Icons.favorite_border)),
                selectedIcon:
                    Container(height: 200, child: Icon(Icons.favorite)),
                label: Text(''),
              ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("demo"),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          NavigationRail(
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
            labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.selected,
            destinations: [
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon:
                    Container(height: 200, child: Icon(Icons.favorite_border)),
                selectedIcon:
                    Container(height: 200, child: Icon(Icons.favorite)),
                label: Text(''),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.book),
                label: Text(''),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.star_border),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.star),
                label: Text(''),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
          // This is the main content.
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Text('selectedIndex: $_selectedIndex'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it didn't work for me, unfortunately.
The elements of the NavigationRail still have the same size.

Comment: Actually, not only do they have the same size, but their width and height are the same. I can't manage to do what you did with your gif.

Comment: Nevermind, I got your solution working in my project when I used "labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.selected,". However, this allows for me to set the height to be greater than the width, but what I want is the opposite: to make the width of each element greater than its height. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Even though they have updated the widget since this question was originally posted, you might encounter a similar issue if you use your own custom widgets (for example an SVG image) in the icon parameter inside of a NavigationRailDestination. The trick is then to set the ***extended*** parameter to ***true*** inside of the NavigationRail, as well as setting the ***labeltype*** to ***NavigationRailLabelType.none***